# How to access content from child object in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I want to get "image_url" from the following JSON code:

```
{
  "recipe": {
    "publisher": "Closet Cooking",
    "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/35382",
    "ingredients": [
      "2 jalapeno peppers, cut in half lengthwise and seeded",
      "2 slices sour dough bread",
      "1 tablespoon butter, room temperature",
      "2 tablespoons cream cheese, room temperature",
      "1/2 cup jack and cheddar cheese, shredded",
      "1 tablespoon tortilla chips, crumbled\n"
    ],
    "source_url": "http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/04/jalapeno-popper-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
    "recipe_id": "35382",
    "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg",
    "social_rank": 100,
    "publisher_url": "http://closetcooking.com",
    "title": "Jalapeno Popper Grilled Cheese Sandwich"
  }
}
```

With the following code in java, using the libraries from "java-json.jar":

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONObject recipe = new JSONObject(myResponse.getJSONObject("recipe"));
ImageURL = recipe.getString("image_url");
```

I can create the JSONObject "recipe" however, when the next line is executed, I get an error message reading that "image_url" is not found.

response is the the raw text I get from a preceding URL request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
System.out.println(json.getJSONObject("recipe").get("image_url"));
```

This is JSONObject from `import org.primefaces.json.JSONObject;`

Also here is the approach you are doing:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("recipe");
String imageUrl = json2.getString("image_url");
System.out.println(imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need debug or log something to check your input.
I just do a test and get the result.

In my opinion, it maybe because your response is not like you write.

- the source code:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * @description: add your desc
 * @author: walker
 * @create: 2019-06-21 13:06
 **/

public class JSONTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws JSONException {
        String json = "\t\t{\n" +
                "\t\t\t\"recipe\": {\n" +
                "\t\t\t\"publisher\": \"Closet Cooking\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"f2f_url\": \"http://food2fork.com/view/35382\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"ingredients\": [\n" +
                "\t\t\t\"2 jalapeno peppers, cut in half lengthwise and seeded\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"2 slices sour dough bread\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"1 tablespoon butter, room temperature\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"2 tablespoons cream cheese, room temperature\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"1/2 cup jack and cheddar cheese, shredded\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"1 tablespoon tortilla chips, crumbled\\n\"\n" +
                "    ],\n" +
                "\t\t\t\"source_url\": \"http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/04/jalapeno-popper-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"recipe_id\": \"35382\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"image_url\": \"http://static.food2fork.com/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"social_rank\": 100,\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"publisher_url\": \"http://closetcooking.com\",\n" +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\"title\": \"Jalapeno Popper Grilled Cheese Sandwich\"\n" +
                "\t\t}\n" +
                "\t\t}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject  recipe = new JSONObject(jsonObject.get("recipe").toString());
        System.out.println(recipe);
        System.out.println(recipe.get("image_url"));
    }
}
```

the result:

```
{"social_rank":100,"f2f_url":"http:\/\/food2fork.com\/view\/35382","recipe_id":"35382","publisher_url":"http:\/\/closetcooking.com","image_url":"http:\/\/static.food2fork.com\/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg","publisher":"Closet Cooking","ingredients":["2 jalapeno peppers, cut in half lengthwise and seeded","2 slices sour dough bread","1 tablespoon butter, room temperature","2 tablespoons cream cheese, room temperature","1\/2 cup jack and cheddar cheese, shredded","1 tablespoon tortilla chips, crumbled\n"],"title":"Jalapeno Popper Grilled Cheese Sandwich","source_url":"http:\/\/www.closetcooking.com\/2011\/04\/jalapeno-popper-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html"}
http://static.food2fork.com/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg
```